# Downgrade from kernel 5.15.0 to 5.8

Tags: downgrade

What are the steps to downgrade an Ubuntu VM with OS 20.04 kernel 5.15 to Ubuntu OS 20.04 kernel 5.04?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but 5.8 is no longer a *supported* kernel, hasn't received security fixes/patches for more than a year, and 5.15 is the *supported* kernel for more than once release; so moving to 5.4 maybe an option for a *supported* kernel for your *unstated* OS/release but you gave no details.

Comment: Asking to downgrade a kernel will *usually* amount to an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (and probably a bad choice in the end). You haven't stated why you think downgrading the kernel might be a good idea?

Comment: downgrade an Ubuntu VM with OS 20.04 kernel 5.15 to Ubuntu OS 20.04 kernel 5.04 in order to be able to use Azure Dependency Agent which is only supported on kernel 5.04.

Comment: There is no downgrading: install the kernel and select the kernel from grub menu.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack contains the steps for both ways (ie. GA to HWE & HWE to GA).  The default *kernel stack* installed is set by the ISO used to instal